# How to return an index of the array that contains a substring?

Tags: python

Example, I have this

```
list = [('motor', 2),('steel',1),('metal',4)]
```

How do I get the index of the row that contains the word metal? I tried using

```
list.index('metal')
```

but it says that metal is not in the list.

Comment: seems to me that you need a dictionary to make it work

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: As an answer has pointed out already, you can't access a tuple using index, and you have tuples as the elements of your list. Could you convert your list to a dictionary in your program?

Comment: Should the answer be `4` or `2`?

Comment: I don't think that your array is correct, check that once. Just paste it in browser console and see it's value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "it says that metal is not in the list."

And it's correct. The `"metal"` string isn't an element of your list (which shouldn't be called `list`, by the way), it's an element of a tuple of your list. `index()` method returns an index only if there's an exact match:

```
data = [('motor', 2),('steel',1),('metal',4)]
print(data.index(('metal',4)))
# 2
```

If you want the second element of the tuple in which `'metal'` is, you could just use a `dict` :

```
print(dict(data)['metal'])
# 4
```

If you want the indices of the tuples which contain `'metal'`, you could use:

```
print([i for i in range(len(data)) if 'metal' in data[i]])
# [2]
```

If you want the first index only, see [@tobias_k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344184/how-to-return-an-index-of-the-array-that-contains-a-substring/43344320#43344320).

Comment: What if my array is: list = [['motor', 2],['steel',1],['metal',4]], to get the index of metal, would there be an easier way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can not just use `index`, since each element in the list is actually a `tuple` of elements. You can [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate) the list and return the [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#next) element that contains the given string, using `in`, or `-1` if no such element can be found.

```
>>> lst = [('motor', 2), ('steel', 1), ('metal', 4)]
>>> next((i for i, tp in enumerate(lst) if "metal" in tp), -1)
2
>>> next((i for i, tp in enumerate(lst) if "foo" in tp), -1)
-1
```

If those tuples always have two elements and you know which element would match, you can also use tuple-unpacking inside of the generator expression and compare to one of the values directly instead of using `in`

```
>>> next((i for i, (x, y) in enumerate(lst) if (x == "metal")), -1)
2
```

Also, better not use `list` as a variable name, as it shadows the built-in type.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know `next` accepts a fallback value instead of throwing a StopIteration. Would a falsey value be a better choice than `-1`, which could be interpreted as an index?

Comment: @EricDuminil You would have to check either way, but you could also just return `None` or let `next` raise the exception, like `index` does.